# XML minidom parsing error

Tags: python, xml, html-parsing, minidom

I am trying to parse `www.amazon.com` source HTML as follows using xml minidom.

```
def start_parser(self, analysis_id, url):
    dom = None
    path = self.create_analysis_folder(analysis_id)
    self.get_generated_html(url)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith('.html'):
                dom = parseString(open(path + '/' +file).read())
                shutil.rmtree(os.getcwd())
        break
    return dom
```

The method does some basic folder manipulations and then calls `parseString` giving it the html source code. I get the following error on execution.

`xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 20, column 20`

Can someone please explain what that means and how to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the HTML is not valid XML and can not be parsed as such. Well formed documents are described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_document).

An invalid token was seen in the document source - take a look at the HTML data to see what character is causing the problem - probably it is an unescaped character, e.g. `&` instead of `&amp;`. Since you parsing HTML that you have not authored, it's likely that you will encounter other issues, e.g. unmatched closing tags, etc.

```
>>> from xml.dom.minidom import parseString

>>> parseString('<html></html>')
<xml.dom.minidom.Document instance at 0x7fc804d02ab8>

>>> parseString('<html>&</html>')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 1931, in parseString
    return expatbuilder.parseString(string)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 940, in parseString
    return builder.parseString(string)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 223, in parseString
    parser.Parse(string, True)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 7
```

You should use a HTML parser, e.g. [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), `lxml.html`, etc.